# What meme is "Track and Field" responsible for?

Tags: track-and-field

[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) once [wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56998/you-can-accept-an-answer-in-0-seconds-looks-weird/57000#57000):

> > clicked again and again until finally I saw "You can accept an
> >     answer in 0 seconds".
>
> For some reason when you said that I
>   was thinking of this.
>
> [image]

What meme to do with "Track and Field" by Konami is being referred to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [the Wikipedia page about the game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_&_Field_%28video_game%29) explains, the game is about pressing buttons repeatedly:

> - 100 Meter Dash – Running by **quickly alternating button presses**.
> - Long jump – Running by **alternating button press** and correct timing for jump. Hold jump button to set angle.
> - Javelin throw – Running by **alternating button presses** and then using action button correct timing for angle (~42 degrees is optimal).
> - 110 Meter Hurdles – Running by **alternating button presses** and using action button to time hurdles
> - Hammer throw – Spinning initiated by pressing a run button once and then correctly timed press of action button to choose angle (45 is optimal).
> - High jump – Running (speed set by computer) and then action button must be held down to determine angle of jump. Once in the air, **the run button can be rapidly pressed** for additional height.

Well, what the asker of that Meta question did was...

> **clicked again and again** until finally I saw "You can accept an answer in 0 seconds".

It's not a meme, but the analogy should be clear by now :)

Comment: If you'd had the misfortune to play only the trackball version (IIRC those were the vast minority: virtually all the T&F machines I saw used buttons), then it would have made no sense at all!